# Firebase vs Nginx Static Files Hosting

Tags: firebase, nginx, static, firebase-hosting

Currently, I am hosting my static files on Firebase (dev environment) and Nginx (Prod Environment). However, I noticed that Firebase hosting is 5 times faster than Ngnix. When I take a look at the network tab, the files are much smaller compare to Nginx. How can this be? Can I achieve the same thing using Nginx?

Firebase:
[image]

Nginx:
[image]

Comment: They're probably gzipping them. That said, those files have different hashes, which means they've got different contents. An apples-to-apples comparison would be more useful.

Comment: I'm sure they're the same. I've downloaded and check the file content and size myself. So I guess gZipping is the reason why?